# Oracle Update table to set specific attribute value in semicolon separated values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column where I have values like:

```
Email_Password+oi8hu907b;New_eMail+Y;Email_Username+iugbhijhb8
```

Now I want to update New_eMail attribute for all rows which has `Y` to `N` without affecting anything else.

Please advise.

Comment: You should fix your broken data model instead. Do **not** store delimited values in a single column.

Comment: That's not an option.

Comment: Your table is not normalized. Consider fixing the design as a permanent fix. As of now, use **REPLACE**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hate it but...

```
update table
   set column = replace(column,'New_eMail+Y','New_eMail+N')
where column like '%New_eMail+Y%'
```

you don't need the WHERE clause but if you put a functional index on the table it may be quicker with it

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a slight improvement over the answer from user davegreen100
Since they don't allow me to post it as a comment, I add it here.

```
update <<tablename>>
  set <<columnname>> = replace(<<columnname>>,';New_eMail+Y;',';New_eMail+N;')
where <<columnname>> like '%;New_eMail+Y;%'
```

Comment: not sure your "improvement" will work, you are missing the % on the LIKE statement

Answer (score 1):

Since it may be the only place in the string where '+Y;' occurs the following statement may do the trick:

```
update <your_table> 
  set <your_column> = replace(<your_column>,'+Y;','+N;')
  where instr(<your_column>,'+Y;')>0
```

This solution differs from the others provided because it does not depend on the value of the email address.